# Why the subscribe function does not populate my property?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, http, observable

I have a problem here, i want to populate my property with the data that i get from the backend, but i dont know why my subscribe function does not populate it, check my code:

Here is my *app.component.ts* code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  schedulings: Scheduling[] = [];

  constructor(private schedulingService: SchedulingService) {
    this.getSchedulings();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.schedulings);
  }

  getSchedulings(): void {
    this.schedulingService.getSchedulings()
      .subscribe((s) => (this.schedulings = s));
  }
}
```

And here is my *scheduling.service.ts* code:

```
export class SchedulingService {
  private readonly apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/schedulings";
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  getSchedulings(): Observable<Scheduling[]> {
    return this.http.get<Scheduling[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }

}
```

The way the code is now the console.log function returns a empty list, but when i use a .pipe function with tap(console.log) it print all the schedulings on the console, so the angular gets the data from the backend without errors, but i want to populate the property schedulings with all the data.
I know this is a basic and dumb question but i'll be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: Your `console.log()` is inside the `ngOnInit()` method. This method only runs once when the component loads, but your API response might be a couple of seconds behind from load. So as a result your logging will show an initially empty array. You should look into [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) method if you want your component to react when something changes.

Comment: but even if i put the console.log() under the subscribe function it still printing a empty list

when i put a console.log in the subscribe function it work, but when the subscribe is finished the property get empty again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP requests are asynchronous and take time to complete, if you want code to execute after the request completes, put the code in the subscribe callback.

```
  getSchedulings(): void {
    this.schedulingService.getSchedulings()
      .subscribe((s) => {
        this.schedulings = s;
        console.log(this.schedulings);
        this.doMoreStuff();
      });
  }
```

---

If you prefer a more synchronous style, you can use `async` / `await` with `firstValueFrom()`.

```
  async getSchedulings(): void {
    this.schedulings = await firstValueFrom(this.schedulingService.getSchedulings());
    console.log(this.schedulings);
  }
```

Comment: i noticed that when i try to use console.log() outside subscribe() function the schedulings property goes back to being empty, i think its because it needs a delay or something, how can i fix this?

Comment: The http request is asynchronous and takes time. Calling subscribe simply initiates the request and then moves on. Code outside of the subscribe call will always be executed before the callback function passed as a parameter. The callback function does not get executed until the request completes. You can research the JavaScript event loop if you are still confused.

Comment: Clarification: when all other synchronous code is done executing, only then will your app check to see if your http request is completed. If the request is complete, then the callback function will be executed.

Comment: @NikolasTrapp I've added the `async` `await` method that you might prefer. You can picture `await` as blocking execution until the http request is done. In reality it just wraps the code underneath into a callback function, similar to the parameter of `subscribe`.

Comment: now i understand the source of the problem, but there is no way to do this without using subscribe?

Comment: @NikolasTrapp did I not just show you a solution without using subscribe?